# Return the result of the save

Tags: java, string, vector, return

In this block of code I am confused on how exactly I would return the result of the save. I attempted `return saveVector;` and return `baseDirectory;` ,but obviously I can't convert the vector to a string. I am a noob to coding so any help here would be appreciated and I would love you to rip this already existing code to pieces.

```
public String add(String category, Question q) {
    // Get the vector of questions from a category file
    Vector<Question> Q = new Vector<Question>();
    // Add the question object to the vector
    Q.add(q);
    // Save the vector back to the category file
    ObjectOutputStream saveVector = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(baseDirectory));
    // Return the result of the save operation
    return saveVector;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code, as well as what you are trying to achieve. The code you've currently posted creates a new Vector, adds an element, and leaves it to rot as you go on and create an ObjectOutputStream, which I doubt should even be in the add() method.

Comment: Ok. This is a project with three separate classes to work with. I know that this block is just wrong and needs the most work, but I'm so lost on how to get it to work correctly. I can link all three classes if that will help.

Comment: Creator: <http://ideone.com/N1AUR1>  Question:  <http://ideone.com/hhyHsk>   QuestionManager:    <http://ideone.com/sTUVkK>

Comment: That's a good start. Now, what exactly are you trying to achieve? what should add() do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String add(String category, Question q) {
    // Get the vector of questions from a category file
    Vector<Question> Q = new Vector<Question>();
    // Add the question object to the vector
    Q.add(q);
    // Save the vector back to the category file
    ByteArrayOutputStream saveVector = new ByteArrayOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(baseDirectory));
    // Return the result of the save operation
    return new String(saveVector.toByteArray());
}
```

use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) instead and create a new String from the ByteArray of the ByteArrayOutputStream.